# could not open database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I typed `cd generate` and then `rake db:migrate`, but the CMD shows that **rake aborted could not open database** you can refer to **chap2** of the book [Ruby on Rails] *OReilly Head First Rails Jan A learner's companion to Ruby on Rails 2009*

```
# SQLite version 3.x
# gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard)
development: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/development.sqlite3 timeout: 5000
# Warning: The database defined as 'test' will be erased and # re-generated from your development database when you run 'rake'.
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/test.sqlite3 timeout: 5000
production: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/production.sqlite3 timeout: 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your database is not properly configured. Make sure that `config/database.yml` matches the settings for your computer, and that you can log into the database on the host and port specified with the username and password specified.

It might help to see `config/database.yml` and the details of your database setup.

Comment: # SQLite version 3.x # gem install sqlite3-ruby (not necessary on OS X Leopard) development: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/development.sqlite3 timeout: 5000 # Warning: The database defined as 'test' will be erased and # re-generated from your development database when you run 'rake'. # Do not set this db to the same as development or production. test: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/test.sqlite3 timeout: 5000 production: adapter: sqlite3 database: db/production.sqlite3 timeout: 5000 Matchu

Comment: @tjw1135, use the [edit] link under your post to include the contents there -- trying to read formatted text via a comment is pretty painful.

Answer (score 0):

If your `config/database.yml` and adapter are configured correctly, try running `rake db:create:all` before running `rake db:migrate`